# Head of blockchain fall back to 0 after unsafe shutdown, how to reset it to the latest?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

System information

Geth version: 1.8.27
OS & Version: Linux
Docker version: 18.09.0

Background

gcmode is full, syncmode is fast. Single node in private network. datadir mount to docker volume.

Problem

I restart the docker so that geth quit unsafely

```
sudo service docker restart
```

When I restart the geth, the latest block become 0.

```js
eth.blockNumber
> 0
```

it was 140000, so 140000 minded blocks are missing.
However, I still can get data of old blocks

```js
eth.getBlock(140000);
> {data of this block}
```

So it looks like blocks still exist but the head of chain reset to 0.

Questions

1 Does full gcmode cause this issue?

2 Is there a way to reset the head? I tried

```js
debug.setHead("0x222E0");
```

but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried everything.
The only way worked:

1. export all block data by run golang code

```
chainClient, err := ethclient.Dial("./db/geth.ipc")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fh, err := os.OpenFile("./aaa", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC, os.ModePerm)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer fh.Close()

var writer io.Writer = fh
for nr := 0; nr <= ___ 140000____; nr++ {
    blockNumber := big.NewInt(int64(nr))
    // blockNumber.Int64(nr)
    block, err := chainClient.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if block == nil {
        log.Fatalf("export failed on #%d: not found", nr)
    }
    if err := block.EncodeRLP(writer); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

2. `geth init`
3. `geth import aaa`

Then everything is right. `eth.blockNumber` is no longer zero.